# 1990s softcore sci-fi movie with a female cop that turns into a nymphomaniac, and Adam and Eve (or something like that) appearing near the end

Tags: story-identification, movie

1990s softcore flick. This female cop turns into a nymphomaniac that screws any stranger she sees after being infected by some kind of extraterrestrial virus or influence or possession or something. At one point a busboy comes into the place and he says “I’m just a busboy” to which she replies “You look more like a big boy to me.”

Also at the end of the movie Adam and Eve are seen, or maybe something like that. I believe the movie also featured some guy getting raped by his mother because she needed to be impregnated by him for some reason, and the guy says at one point when she is screwing him and he is trying to not splooge, “Stop, I can’t hold it anymore.”

Comment: This is probably going to be one of the *Species* films.

Comment: Upvote for the phrase "trying to not splooge"

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 3):

Two answers deleted for abusive language seem to nonetheless have gotten the answer correct. *[Sex Files: Alien Erotica](https://imdb.com/title/tt0208676/)* matches on most of the provided points.

[image: Movie poster for *Sex Files: Alien Erotica]

> Two government agents investigate a virus that causes people to become uncontrollably sexually excited.

The cast page mentions an Adam, an Eve and a busboy.

Comment: http://monster-crap.blogspot.com/2014/08/monster-crap-inductee-alien-files-aka.html?m=1 has more of a plot rundown